# Unable to Assign value to variable from inside a method

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working with Google Maps JS API. I'm trying to set a marker at the center of my map. I'm using the `currLocation` variable to hold the current location. The `currLocation` variable has value within the inline private method ( Section 1), but it is null when I want to set a marker(Section 2).

Stackoverflow had lot of solutions for "Unable to set value to global variable", but I couldn't solve my issue with their reference.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function initMap() {

    var currLocation = null;

    var defaultCenter = { lat: 34.397, lng: 150.644 };

    //Set Map properties 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
        scrollwheel: true,
        zoom: 10
    });


    //Get Current Location - Section 1 
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            currLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(currLocation);
        });
    }
    else {
        map.setCenter(defaultCenter);
    }

    //Put marker on the current location - Section 2
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currLocation,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem lies within your control flow logic. If the first feature detection fails (I.e., `if(navigator.geolocation)`) (from your description, it sounds exactly like that), then the value of `currLocation` will remain null. If, it is not desirable to continue without `currLocation` then:

1. Throw an exception from your `else` block as, navigator does not have geolocation.
2. Set it to an acceptable default other than `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to put the marking function inside the success callback of getCurrentPosition. Because it's an asynchronous function. currLocation would be null until the success callback function is called.